# Draw SVG Ellipse from Equation

Tags: javascript, math, d3.js, svg

I have the equation of an ellipse, `2x² + (1)y² = 100`, which corresponds to the general form equation `ax² + by² = r`.

I would like to visualize this an ellipse in an SVG where each unit of height is represented by one pixel.

SVGs draw ellipses in this manner:

```
<ellipse rx=200 ry=100 cx="0" cy="200" fill="silver" stroke="gray"/>
```

Where `rx` and `ry` represent "x radius" and "y radius", respectively.

However, the `rx` and `ry` values do not correspond to the discriminants `2` and `1` in the equation. Plugging `2` and `1` in as `rx` and `ry` do not make an ellipse of the same proportions as the equation.

How do I draw the Ellipse represented by the equation as an SVG?

Comment: That’s a maths question rather than a programming question. But check-out the Wikipedia entry for ellipse, under Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: The formula for an ellipse is usually written x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the equation,

`2x² + 1y² = 100`

and replacing `2` and `1` with the variables `dX` and `dY`, and `100` with `r` (radius), we get:

`dx * x² + dy * y² = r`

In which case, the Ellipse is drawn as:

```
<ellipse rx=${Math.sqrt( r / dX )} ry=${Math.sqrt( r / dY )} cx="0" cy="200"/>
```